# How to avoid NO_COLUMN error in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I'm trying to query from several sheets on the same spreadsheet, with a condition. but always getting the following error no matter what i did:

> "NO_COLUMN: col1"

here is the query:

```
=QUERY({'Shipment Detail Report DHL Ship'!A2:E;Taxi!A2:E;Migvan!A2:E;Lapid!A2:E},"Select * where col1 is not null",0)
```

Can someone solve this strange case?

Answer (score 2):

use `Col1` instead of `col1`

```
=QUERY({'Shipment Detail Report DHL Ship'!A2:E;Taxi!A2:E;Migvan!A2:E;Lapid!A2:E},
 "select * where Col1 is not null", 0)
```